# $(\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}) \cup (-1,1)$ simply connected?

Tags: complex-analysis

How does one show simply connectedness? It is painfully obvious to me geometrically, but this isn't a proof.

Comment: Star-shaped with center (0,0).

Answer (score 4):

There are several different ways. One way is to note that it's a [star domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain), so it's contractible via a straight line homotopy and thus simply connected.